# how should i use glutPostRedisplay in a loop to call display multiple times when an event occures?

Tags: opengl, glut

i am new to opengl.
i want to draw my scene a few times when the user presses some key, i have called glutPostRedisplay in a for loop when the key is pressed but it just redraws my scene one time. how should i handle this problem?

Answer (score 2):

First off, *glutPostRedisplay* is a function that belongs to GLUT, which is not part of OpenGL but a 3rd party library/framework. There are other frameworks, or you can do everything from scratch (heck, I just remembered, that when I began learning OpenGL some 14 years ago, GLUT won't properly work for me, so I did write my framework from scratch then).

> i want to draw my scene a few times when the user presses some key

**Never** mix drawing and animation logic with event processing. If the user pressed a key that triggers some animation, set a flag (=some variable), that the animation should be played and then iterate through the animation in your render/animation loop.

> i have called glutPostRedisplay in a for loop when the key is pressed but it just redraws my scene one time

glutPostRedisplay won't trigger a redraw immediately. It sets a flags, that the GLUT message loop shouls issue a redraw instead of going idle after all message processing. Of course this flag doesn't accumulate.

So here's a layout using GLUT. Unfortunately GLUT is subobtimal for this kind of things, because it doesn't give you control over the event loop, which makes precise timing cumbersome to achieve.

```
time_t rendertimer;
void stopwatch(time_t); // some external helper function that reports time between calls

typedef enum {stop, play} animstate;

struct animation {
    float time;
    float duration;
    animstate state;
};

animation animations[...];

void keyboard(key, x, y)
{
    if(key == ...) {
        animations[0].time = 0;
        animations[0].state = play;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void idle()
{
    float deltaT = stopwatch(rendertimer);

    if( animation[...].state == play ) {
        animation[...].time += deltaT;
        if( animation[...].duration <= animation[...].time ) {
             animation[...].state = stop;
        }
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display()
{
    draw_objects_according_to_animation();
}
```

Comment: i usually plop it into the glutIdleFunc callback